# when i download apps from my computer to send to my new motorola i1 they go to my old phone

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

My Problem:

- My device doesn't show up on **Google play**.
- Only *my old phone*, the one my Grandmother is using.
- The apps I download **go to her phone**!

Please help!

Comment: Did you sign into your Google account on the new phone?

Answer (score 4):

If you have more than one device registered with your email it should show in the google play store a dropdown list (choose a device) after you click install.

Something like this.

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/25frdy0.jpg]